# Django Rest Framework Simple JWT getting anonymous user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I want to use Rest Framework simpleJWT as authentication earlier I was using Django default authentication.
Here are views currently I am **getting AnonymousUser error**,  what changes do I need to get a user request from JWT Authenticated user. I want to get a request.user from a jWT Authenticated user. Please help me out.

```py
class MessagesModelList(ListView):
    http_method_names = ['get', ]
    paginate_by = getattr(settings, 'MESSAGES_PAGINATION', 500)

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.kwargs.get('dialog_with'):
            qs = MessageModel.objects \
                .filter(Q(recipient=self.request.user, sender=self.kwargs['dialog_with']) |
                        Q(sender=self.request.user, recipient=self.kwargs['dialog_with'])) \
                .select_related('sender', 'recipient')
        else:
            qs = MessageModel.objects.filter(Q(recipient=self.request.user) |
                                             Q(sender=self.request.user)).prefetch_related('sender', 'recipient', 'file')

        return qs.order_by('-created')

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        user_pk = self.request.user.pk
        data = [serialize_message_model(i, user_pk)
                for i in context['object_list']]
        page: Page = context.pop('page_obj')
        paginator: Paginator = context.pop('paginator')
        return_data = {
            'page': page.number,
            'pages': paginator.num_pages,
            'data': data
        }
        return JsonResponse(return_data, **response_kwargs)


class DialogsModelList(ListView):
    http_method_names = ['get', ]
    paginate_by = getattr(settings, 'DIALOGS_PAGINATION', 20)

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = DialogsModel.objects.filter(Q(user1_id=self.request.user.pk) | Q(user2_id=self.request.user.pk)) \
            .select_related('user1', 'user2')
        return qs.order_by('-created')

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        # TODO: add online status
        user_pk = self.request.user.pk
        data = [serialize_dialog_model(i, user_pk)
                for i in context['object_list']]
        page: Page = context.pop('page_obj')
        paginator: Paginator = context.pop('paginator')
        return_data = {
            'page': page.number,
            'pages': paginator.num_pages,
            'data': data
        }
        return JsonResponse(return_data, **response_kwargs)


class SelfInfoView(DetailView):
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        user: AbstractBaseUser = context['object']
        data = {
            "username": user.get_username(),
            "pk": str(user.pk)
        }
        return JsonResponse(data, **response_kwargs)


class UploadView(CreateView):
    http_method_names = ['post', ]
    model = UploadedFile
    form_class = UploadForm

    def form_valid(self, form: UploadForm):
        self.object = UploadedFile.objects.create(
            uploaded_by=self.request.user, file=form.cleaned_data['file'])
        return JsonResponse(serialize_file_model(self.object))

    def form_invalid(self, form: UploadForm):
        context = self.get_context_data(form=form)
        errors_json: str = context['form'].errors.get_json_data()
        return HttpResponseBadRequest(content=json.dumps({'errors': errors_json}))
```

Answer (score 1):

use permission classes in your views

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
class TestView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```